# Color sheme vs program caption and main menu in W10

Tags: delphi, winapi, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I build my software using C++ Builder 2009 (although I believe this is just as relevant for comparable Delphi versions) and the look and feel is 'great' on Windows XP and Windows 7.

On Windows 10, due to the white caption and main menu ... not so good:
It's like a grey blob sticking out, because right under the toolbar, and a few panels, there are far bigger ListView and TreeView controls with color `clWindow`.
My toolbars etc. use (default) color `clBtnFace` .

On Windows 8.1 it doesn't like too bad, despite the white caption.  I think it's because `clBtnFace` is a lighter grey and because the main menu is a shade of grey as well.

[image: clBtnFace on Windows 10]

Looking at Windows 10 file explorer, ps. my software also explores files, the grey toolbar etc. have been replaced by the same white as the white in the ListView.  Although I'm not entirely sure the color code is also `clWindow` ?  It certainly is not `clBtnFace` anymore since the latter color code still maps to a grey value.

I experimented with changing the panels's color to `clWindow` and (I think) the look on Windows 10 is better this way.  It looks more like W10 Explorer.

[image: clWindow on Windows 10]

My question.  Any idea what color code is used here (I assume it's not a hard coded color)?  Is it `clWindow` ?  Or another code ?
I preferable would like to use the same color code that W10 uses, so that when the system is tweaked with different colors, these panels etc. also get the chosen look (This is also important for high contrast settings etc. for people with vision problems).

Your input appreciated.

Comment: @Jan did you remove the Delphi tag ?  I may use Builder, but since this issue relies heavily on VCL I think it is just as relevant for Delphi and this way the circle of people who may know an answer is bigger.

Comment: Delphi isn't really relevant here. Nor is C++ Builder. It should best be tagged winapi.

Comment: @David.  Fair enough but I still need to know how to do it in Borland C++ Builder, since I use VCL to create the mentioned controls.  It would be the same on Delphi.

Comment: That's the easy part. Don't worry about that part yet.